# How to recover mysql data files from docker containers

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

The guy who setting up `snipe/snipe-it` was leaving from our company couple months ago. He installed that `snipe/snipe-it` with docker and found that server (EC2 instance) was crashed and cannot recover anymore as not starting up anymore. That's why I've created another EC2 instance and copied all of files inside old EC2 instance to new EC2 instance. Now, I'm struggling that how could I recover mysql data inside docker in old EC2 instance volume.

I found that some folders (as docker containers) inside `var/lib/docker/overlay2/` but I have not found mysql data file inside there. Please let me know how to recover it, thanks.

Comment: If you have access to the Dockerfiles used to create the image you might be able to figure out the voulmes bound to the image (like `path/in/the/instance:/var/mysql/data`) and try to recover those files. Otherwise, if the containers had no volumes I'm afraid all persistence was lost when deleting the containers.

Comment: If you've run it using this docker-compose file, then the data is in the `db` volume https://github.com/snipe/snipe-it/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: @ppicom the thing is there is no hangover document that's why I don't have any information that how did he run it before with dockerfile or docker-compose.

Comment: @HansKilian I think he ran with `docker run` command before.

Comment: Without knowledge about how it was run, it's really hard to help you find the data. One thing you can try is list the volumes on the host and see if there's anything that looks like it might be what you're looking for. Try `docker volume ls`.

Comment: @HansKilian the thing is the instance was crashed so I've copied the data inside that instance and mount into new instance. that's why I cannot use `docker volume 
 ls`. I may need to install `docker` again.